# Cannot Capture Value From Nested Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase database structured below:

[image]

Essentially, I am trying to capture the value of "answer." I am running the below code:

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //should dump all of poll creators items in the following section of the current user
                        Log.v("DataSnap", dataSnapshot.toString());
                        Log.v("DataSnap", dataSnapshot.child(USER_ID_LABEL).getValue().toString());
                        ArrayList<String > mPollAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot y : dataSnapshot.child(ANSWERS_LABEL).getChildren()){
                            Log.v("ANSWER", y.getValue().toString());
                        }
```

And unfortunately it is returning both "vote count" and "answer," when I strictly want the value of answer:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the top-level keys e.g L3l1..., "answers" and "1", firebase will return the resultant object in the form of a `Hashmap<String, Object>` where `Object` can be anything.

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    firebaseDatabase.getReference("<top-level-key>")
            .child("L3l1...")
            .child("answers")
            .child("1")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //Returns a hashmap with keys of type answer and vote_count
                    Object value = dataSnapshot.getValue(); /
                    Object o = ((HashMap) value).get("answer");
                    String s = "";
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

2. **A more elegant solution**
   To Simplify things, create an `Answer` class and cast it to the datasnapshot.

   ```
   public class Answer {
       private int vote_count;
       private String answer;

       public Answer() {
       }

       public int getVote_count() {
           return vote_count;
       }

       public void setVote_count(int vote_count) {
           this.vote_count = vote_count;
       }

       public String getAnswer() {
           return answer;
       }

       public void setAnswer(String answer) {
           this.answer = answer;
       }
   }
   ```

In your Activity or wherever you call firebase:

```
//In your Activity or Fragment or wherever you call Firebase
        firebaseDatabase.getReference("<top-level-key>")
            .child("L13a")
            .child("answers")
            .child("1")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    Answer value = dataSnapshot.getValue(Answer.class);
                    //value.getAnswer() = "rstrrs"
                    //value.getVote_Count() = 0
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: If you give me some more time, I can properly cast the variables for you

Comment: I modified my answer

Comment: Interesting on your answer class - the problem is I already have a Polll class modeled and mapped to the Firebase JSON.....not sure if this impacts the Answer class

Comment: You can model the class whichever way makes sense for your business rules. All you will have to do, is as you said map it directly to the Firebase JSON tree structure.